# How to replace highest record values using lag or lead or recursive in select query

Tags: mysql

conditional based select query with inthe select column

This table holds hearingscreening results. Every personid can have multiple records.

[image]

In the case 1 :

- the highest `recordid` is `4` has to compare with `3,2,1` records of `personid`.
- if `leftresult` or `rightresult` of 4th `recordid` has values (`1,2,12`) then the select query has to check the `recordid 3`.
- if the 3rd record has best year value as 1 then `lefresult` and `rightresult` of 4th record has to be [`Null,2`] respectively.
- However, since `rightresult` is again `2` then it has to check with 2th `recordid` of `personid` because it can be have values this range (`1,2,12`).

Below is the input records and mentioned expected `outrecords`:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (
    personid INT NULL,
    leftresult INT NULL,
    rightresult INT NULL,
    bestear INT NULL,
    recordid UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (33122,1,1,0,2);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (33122,6,7,0,1);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (41228,1,1,0,3);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (41228,1,8,0,2);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (41228,6,7,0,1);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (45336,1,1,0,3);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (45336,Null,8,1,2);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (45336,1,1,0,1);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (54122,NULL,2,1,2);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (54122,6,6,0,1);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (371339,2,2,0,4);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (371339,NULL,2,1,3);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (371339,3,3,0,2);
INSERT INTO Prod_data_v2.data_meaareport (371339,3,3,0,1);
```

My attempted query

```
select m1.personid,m1.leftresult,m1.rightresult,m1.bestear,m1.ascrnk, 
case when m1.leftresult in (1,2,12) then (select m2.leftresult from MR m2 where m1.personid = m2.personid and m2.ascrnk = m1.ascrnk -1) end leftlagg 
from MR m1 where m1.personid in (379217,502096,371339,378915) order by m1.personid asc, m1.ascrnk desc
```

Mysql version 8.0.23

Comment: Please post that input records in text form, not as image. We want to be able to copy & paste the data if we want to do testing. Also, please post your attempted query and MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT personid, MAX(recordid) mxr
    FROM data_meaareport
  GROUP BY personid),
  cte2 AS (
SELECT mlr.personid, mxr,
       
     GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(leftresult,'NULL') 
          ORDER BY CASE WHEN leftresult IN (1,2,12) THEN 999 
          WHEN mlr.recordid BETWEEN mxr-1 AND mxr+1 AND leftresult IS NULL THEN 0
          WHEN mlr.recordid BETWEEN mxr-1 AND mxr+1 THEN 1
          ELSE 2
     END) lr,
  
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(rightresult,'NULL') 
          ORDER BY CASE WHEN rightresult IN (1,2,12) THEN 999 
          WHEN mlr.recordid BETWEEN mxr-1 AND mxr+1 AND rightresult IS NULL THEN 0
          WHEN mlr.recordid BETWEEN mxr-1 AND mxr+1 THEN 1
          ELSE 2
     END) rr
  FROM data_meaareport mlr
 JOIN cte 
 ON mlr.personid=cte.personid
GROUP BY mlr.personid, mxr)
SELECT personid,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(lr,',',1) AS fleftresult,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(rr,',',1) AS frightresult,
       mxr AS mrecordid
  FROM cte2;
```

First part is getting `MAX(recordid)` as reference and wrap it in a common table expression (`cte`). Then use `GROUP_CONCAT()` with a very customized `ORDER BY` clause which covers the following conditions; assuming that it is exactly as your condition:

- if `leftresult/rightresult IN (1,2,12)` then assign it as 999 in the order by.
- if `recordid` is between the `MAX(recordid)` plus/minus 1 and `leftresult/rightresult IS NULL`, assign it with `0`.
- if `recordid` is between the `MAX(recordid)` plus/minus 1 THEN assign it with `1`.
- if none of the condition above is matched, then assign it with `2`.

Those query I wrap with another `cte` and do `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the first value from the `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Here's the results based on your current data sample:

| personid | fleftresult | frightresult | mrecordid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33122 | 6 | 7 | 2 |
| 41228 | 6 | 8 | 3 |
| 45336 | NULL | 8 | 3 |
| 54122 | NULL | 6 | 2 |
| 371339 | NULL | 3 | 4 |

Here's a fiddle of my tests: https://dbfiddle.uk/20NSmziE